# Stumped by Run Time error '1004': Unable to set the PrintTitleRows property of the PageSetup class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a sub for the page setup of a sheet. An error message pops up for `.PrintTitleRows = Match`. The sub functions perfectly if I take out that line. I looked into this error on [Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291298/you-cannot-use-page-setup-properties-in-excel-if-no-printers-were-inst), it says "This problem occurs when there are no printer drivers installed on your computer. Excel cannot set or get page setup properties if no printer drivers are installed."

Interestingly, the page lists other properties in the `.PageSetup` class, including `.CenterHeader`, `.PrintQuality`, `.Orientation`, and a host of other properties that are in my code. It would make more sense if this error came up for every property corresponding to the error type, but only `.PrintTitleRows` does it.

Here is my code:

```
Sub PageSetup_General2()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Match As Range

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Application.PrintCommunication = True

Set Match = WS.Cells.Find(What:="Source #", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        'Find Range for .PrintTitleRows
        
With WS.PageSetup
        .CenterHeader = "&F"
        .LeftFooter = "Prepared by " & Application.UserName
        'Sets username, to check what your username is, go to File>Options>General
        .CenterFooter = "&D"
        .RightFooter = "Page &P"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        'Sets arrow margins
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        'Sets Landscape
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .PrintTitleRows = Match
        'Yields error: "Run-time error '1004': "Unable to set the PrintTitleRows property of the PageSetup class"
End With
End Sub
```

I'm messing with `Application.PrintCommunication` and double checking that my printer drivers are installed, but to no avail...Any thoughts on what's going on with this sub?

Comment: What is `Match`? Do you intend it to be the word `"Match"`? `PrintTitleRows` returns or sets a `String` so you need to assign a `String` to it, `Match` isn't a string without the `" "`

Comment: @SamuelEverson ```Match``` is a range I set. If I assign it as a ```String``` and put ```"  "``` around Match in the ```PrintTitleRows``` property, it still doesn't function. Is the problem that I'm going about this wrong with ```Match```?

Comment: @SamualEverson I also tried commenting out the ```Match``` code altogether and putting a string found in the sheet between ```"  "```, but no cigar. I still get the same error.

Comment: My appologies, I completely missed that, try `Match.Address`

Comment: I'm just looking at the doc for this property - might be helpful furthermore: [PrintTitleRows property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printtitlerows)

Comment: @SamualEverson I'm a bit new to VBA (if you couldn't tell)- can you elaborate on the syntax for Match.Address? Does it need to be ```Dim Match.Address As String```, Set Match.Address = ....```, and ```.PrintTitleRows = "Match.Address"?

Comment: @SamuelEverson Resolved! It let me get away with ```Match As Range```, ```Set Match = ...```, and ```.PrintTitleRows = Match.Address```. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `.Address` is a property of a `Range` object - [See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address) - so you only need the `.Address` when you want to return that value from your defined range (you can't set the address property other than by the range itself). To help embed how it works, select some cells on your sheet and in the immidiate window of the VBE, type `?Selection.Address` - it will return the A1 notation address for your selection - e.g. `$A$1:$C$10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although resolved in comments, an answer is best so;

The `PrintTitleRows` property, per [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printtitlerows):

> Returns or sets the rows that contain the cells to be repeated at the top of each page, as a String in **A1-style notation** in the language of the macro. Read/write String.

As such, to get the A1-style notation use the `Range.Address` property - in your case, `Match.Address`. Let's say your range represents cells `A5` to `D5`,  which will return `Match.Address` as  `$A$5:$D$5`

You can reference the [.Address property documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address).

If you want to return the address without the `$` absolute referencing, set the *rowAbsolute* and *columnAbsolute* parameters to `False`, i.e `.Address False, False` which would return `A5:D5`